# Android Studio unresolved dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

When I implementation from githut, it show unresolved dependencies.

[image: Screenshot of unresolved dependencies]

just i update the sdk , it starts wrong,every git could not implementation

creat a new project,nothing to change,but sync also say:-----------------------------

1.Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@d**ebug/compileClasspath**': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

2.Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@**debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath**': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

3.Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@**debugUnitTest/compileClasspath**': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

4.Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@**release/compileClasspath**': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

5.Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@**releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath**': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

Comment: Add your code instead of the image !

Comment: What makes you think "2.x.x" is a version?

Comment: It's worth checking if your gradle is in offline mode. Go to File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Gradle --> Offline Work. If the Offline Work box is checked, uncheck it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid#binaries), you have to replace the `x.x` by the latest version.

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2'
```

Comment: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

ok,I Just solved the problem. It's VPN Proxy problem,It couldn't  download